# How to write the if condition correctly

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have a question about writing the if condition in a loop. Informally, I want the condition to work as follows. I will have a string, and I want to compare it against a `list` of strings. If it does not match any of the values in the list, then go ahead and execute the body of the if statement. If it does match one of the values, skip the body of the if statement. Here is my code (I wrote comments just be clear):

```
Iterator it=row.entrySet().iterator();  
Iterator iter=getPrimaryKey.entrySet().iterator();

Map.Entry pairs=(Map.Entry)it.next();
            if(!(pairs.getKey().equals(iter.next()))){  //this is the condition. I'm talking about. I want the key to run through all the membres of iter. If it is distinct from all of them, go ahead and execute the code in the if statement.
```

Anyways, I do not know what I'm doing wrong so I'd be interested in hearing suggestions.

Comment: If you're using a Map, which your `Map.Entry` implies, you should be able to simply do `if (mymap.get(myTestString) == null) { do things }`
If you're not using a Map you should show the declarations for `row`, and what is `getPrimaryKey`?  Also, the enhanced `for` loop syntax usually lets you stop using an `Iterator` - `for (Object aRow : row) { loop-body }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to check if a string in the "it" iterator is present as one of hte strings in the getPrimaryKey.entrySet(), so you might want to check directly if its contained there.

```
Iterator it=row.entrySet().iterator();  
Iterator iter=getPrimaryKey.entrySet().iterator();

 while(it.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry pairs=(Map.Entry)it.next();
    if(! getPrimaryKey.keySet().contains(pairs.getKey()){ 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you will want to set a flag if it is found, then after the whole list has been traversed, use that flag to determine whether to do the body of the if statement, outside of the `while` loop:

```
boolean found = false;  // start off as not found

// while items available and match not found, keep looking
while(!found && it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if (/* condition */)
        found = true;  // item has been found
}

// if we made it through whole list without finding match, then do stuff
if (!found)
    // do fun things here
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll edit my post. It's unclear right now. The if statement is definitely in the body of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to execute any unique value in the set:

```
if(!row.entrySet().containsValue(pairs.getValue())
   //execute
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `key` you are referring is a `String`. I would write your code as following:

```
    Map<String, Object> row = getTypedRow();
    Map<String, Object> primaryKey = getTypedPrimaryKey();

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = row.entrySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iter = primaryKey.entrySet().iterator();


    for (String key : row.keySet()) {
        if ( ! primaryKey.keySet().contains(key) ) {
            // it will be here only for key from the row that aren't present in the primaryKey map.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this... your iterators are very confusing...

```
/*ASSUMPTIONS*/
Map<String, Object> row = something;
Map<String, Object> primaryKeyMap = something;
/*END ASSUMPTIONS*/

Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entryset = row.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : entryset) {
    if (primaryKeyMap.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
        //do stuff...
        break;
    }
}
```